# Convert integers to strings in particular rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I am trying to convert particular values in given rows of a column into specific strings.

I want the value 1 to be converted to 'never', the value 2 to be converted to 'former' and the value 3 to be converted to 'current'.

However, when I run the following code, I get the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'.

```
newdata = newdf.groupby('smoking-number').mean().reset_index()
sem = newdf.groupby('smoking-number').sem().reset_index()
newdata = newdata.loc[(newdata[['smoking_number']]==1) & (newdata[['smoking_number']]==2) & (newdata[['smoking_number']]==3)] = [['never','former','current']]
```

Would anybody be able to give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 1):

A map should work：

```
newdata['smoking_number'] = newdata['smoking_number'].map({1: 'never', 2: 'former', 3: 'current'})
```

Comment: Thanks!! However, when I add that line, it now gives me the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'. Why might be this be?

Comment: It  should  be  related   to something else. Do  you   have  a  function  `view` called improperly  somewhere in your code ?

Comment: It's pointing to this line: newdata.plot.line(x='smoking-number',y='distance', yerr= sem, ax=axes[0],legend=False)

Comment: It seems like  you want `smoking-number` to be a category column, do you want to use a line plot ? Maybe a bar plot is more suitable ? I'm not sure if you can line plot against a column that contains strings

Comment: sure - I will try a barplot! :) Thanks so much for your help